# What is the condition for NPOT compression in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, compression, textures

im very confused now. Unity 2017 can compress NPOT textures???

[image]
[image]

What is the compression's condition? Anyone have detailed information about this?

I'm using Unity 2017.1.1f1.

Thank you for reading my question !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not Unity, but the compression format. 
ETC2 can compress NPOT textures, but for example ETC1 or PVRTC cannot.

- NPOT texture using ETC2 can be compressed (512x400px,  100kb): 
  [image: NPOT using ETC2 can be compressed]
- NPOT texture using ETC1 cannot be compressed (512x400px,  600kb): 
  [image: NPOT using ETC1 cannot be compressed]

---

If you want to use ETC1 or PVRTC compression with a NPOT texture, you can select a 'Non power of 2' option, (By default is None, but it can be : *To nearest*, *To larger* or *To smaller*.

- NPOT texture using PVRTC and Unity 'Non power of 2 : ToLarger' option, (512x512px, 128kb):
  [image: NPOT texture using PVRTC and Unity 'Non power of 2 : ToLarger' option]

---

Comment: im very appriciated your answer, thank you so much... but please do you know what condition for ETC2 to compress NPOT? i cant find any references about this

Comment: I don't know about specific conditions with ETC2 and NPOT textures. ETC2 requires OpenGL3 and not all the mobile devices have that (I mean, not all the old devices :D `OpenGL ES 3.0 - This API specification is supported by Android 4.3 (API level 18) and higher`).  Well, maybe you can find more info here: https://forum.unity.com/threads/etc1-vs-etc2-texture-compression.219842/ or here: http://www.graphicshardware.org/previous/www_2007/presentations/strom-etc2-gh07.pdf